# How to make it clear I'm violating Command Query Separation

Tags: design-patterns, python

[Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) is a useful principle, though it's not always ideal. Sometimes you need to run a process, which will result in useful data you need to return. My specific case is uploading a file to a server and getting the ID of the file (which is assigned by another system I have no control over).

In simple terms, the function is something like this:

```
def upload_file(filepath):
    # Set up filedata with values
    result = upload_to_server(filedata)
    return result['id']
```

I'm not debating whether or not to disregard CQS, but I am wondering how to make this especially clear to a user. For instance `upload_file` doesn't make the return value explicit, but `get_upload_file` is also ambiguous. A docstring is an obvious must to make the function explicit for anyone who reads that.

But I was wondering are there any other helpful patterns that can make it explicit that a function performs actions *and* returns a value. Or alternatively, should I just focus on making one of these aspects clear and not worry about fully informing the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for python the best practice available would be to note in the docstring that it is a side-effecting function.

```
def upload_file(filepath):
    """
    Uploads a filepath to a server and also returns the remote server id
    """
```

If this were a language like scala or haskell you could communicate this with the type signature of the function, for example:

```
type RemoteServerId = Integer
uploadToServer :: Filepath -> IO RemoteServerId
```

or

```
type RemoteServerId = Int
def uploadToServer(path: Filepath): Task[RemoteServerId]
```

Because python doesn't give you that option, the docstring is your main option.

A supplementary tactic would be to have a naming convention. Perhaps you could be explicit by naming the function `upload_to_server_and_return_remote_id(filepath)`

Comment: Don't forget that python3 also has function annotations, so something like def upload_file(filepath) -> "server-id" : could be done.

Comment: @GlennRogers That makes it a little worse honestly, because that signature gives you no indication that it's a side-effecting function. A function looking up ids in a local mapping would have the same signature

Comment: Except then you'd call the function "get_file_locator" or such :)